# sending free confirm SMS messages using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I'm working with ASP.NET web application and i want to confirm user account after registration using `SMS` messages . the only way i have found is to use `twilio` and i need to buy a number ! which will appear in the "FROM " field as a number not a name in the `SMS`! 
the twilio code i have found is this :

```
 // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account 
        string AccountSid = "..";
        string AuthToken = "[AuthToken]";
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        var message = twilio.SendMessage("[From]", "[To]", null, null, null);
        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
```

my question: is there any way to send a confirm `SMS` for free ? and can i chose the name also in "FROM " field in the messages? please any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send text messages for free using the carrier's email text message address (check out http://www.emailtextmessages.com/ for the formats to use).  It's not as good because it requires users to select their carrier, and carriers can change over time with number porting, but in your case since it's just for initial confirmation the carrier changing isn't a concern.  If I recall correctly, the FROM in this case will show as the email address you send the text from.

An example would be you could text a Verizon customer using 1234567890@vtext.com, assuming the phone number is 123-456-7890.

In order to get a free solution, you might have to make some sacrifice such as going this route.

Comment: then how some companies use their name in FROM ? is it possible for me to do it ?

Comment: @user5067119 I believe that's called "Sender ID" and when using certain SMS providers you can specify what you want it to show as.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's some good suggestions in these answers for free messages, I'd just like to answer from the Twilio perspective too.

You can send SMS messages from Twilio and provide your own sender ID that is not a number. This works in [145 countries listed here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-countries-does-twilio-support-alphanumeric-sender-id). You would send the message in exactly the same way, except you would substitute the sender ID that you want for the `From` number in your example.

It will, however, cost you to send an SMS (as it costs us). Also, if you need to send SMS messages to one of the countries that doesn't support an alphanumeric sender ID, like the US, you will want to fallback to using a number to send the message.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer , but unfortunately the alphanumeric is not supported in my country ! but how the companies in my country have this service with alphanumeric support ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know who is best to send SMS to UAE using an alphanumeric sender ID then.

Answer (score 0):

Most carriers allow sending SMS messages via SMTP.  There's a decent list here: http://martinfitzpatrick.name/list-of-email-to-sms-gateways/, and Google is your friend here.

You could ask the user for their carrier (in a drop down list) as well as their phone number, and then use `SmtpClient` to send an email.  For example, if you wanted to send a SMS message to 1234 on Verizon, the send part might look something like this:

```
SmptClient smpt = new SmptClient(...);
...
if (carrier = "Verizon")
{
    smpt.Send("admin@mysite.com", phoneNumber + "@vtext.com", "Welcome to MySite.com!", "Your account is registered.");
}
```

Obviously you'll need to have a valid Smtp configuration, and you'd probably want to have a more elegant way of parsing carriers, but that's the general idea.

This is not entirely free though - you do need an email server.  You may also run into trouble with carriers if you send too many messages or too many users complain you're spamming them (something I imagine a paid service would handle for you).

Comment: thanks a lot .. but the user will revived the SMS with the name of the email ? like : " from : admin@mysite.com" ?

Comment: When I test it out, it shows up as coming from my email address.  Since I have a contact entry for myself, it shows my name.  If I put a subject, it puts "Subject: Test" in the message body; if I omit the subject, it just shows the message body.

Comment: You won't be able to have it show up as if it came from a phone numbe rwith this method.